# When would a react component not be a pure component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

just been reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

and trying to work out when would a function not return something pure?

surely if you give a component the same props/state then it will always return the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your function component has any side effects, then it would not be a pure component. For example, reading the current time via `Date.now()` is a side effect. If that date is passed via prop, then you're fine. But React/JavaScript cannot guarantee that a function component doesn't have side effects.

Consider the following function components.

```
function Impure() {
  return <p>{Date.now()}</p>
}

function Pure(date) {
  return <p>{date}</p>
}
```

Comment: so safe to assume if things are being passed in then it's probably pure?

Comment: No, since you can imagine that a `date` prop is being passed in, but isn't being used: `function Impure(date) { return <p>{Date.now()}</p> }`

Comment: so are there no rules to know when it will/wont be without looking at the code?

Comment: In JavaScript, that's correct. In Haskell or Elm, you would only need to look at the function's type, and not it's implementation.  When using side effects in those pure, functional languages, the type of that function let's you know that there's a side effect. And if there's no side effect, the type of that function let's you know that there's no side effect.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine if you had a component that showed the weather and a background image of the sun if it's daytime and a background picture of the moon if it's night.

You would pass in the temperature, wind speed etc. through props, but you would display the correct image depending on the time of day.

So, if you pass the temperature of 15 degrees during the day and during the night, the component will look differently even though you have passed the same props.